# Add selected date to Custom ListView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, datepicker, xamarin.forms

I have DatePicker,ListView and Button controls.
After clicking on button "Add", selected date of DatePicker should be added to ListView. 
Model for ListView is like-

```
public class dateListModel
    {
        public string dateSelected { get; set; }
        public string requestFor { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string weekDay { get; set; }

    }
```

[image]

I am using below code to add selected date in List but I am not able to add more than one entry in list.

```
public void onAddClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       

        selectedDates.Add (new dateListModel(){dateSelected=choosedDate.Date.ToString("d"),requestFor=requestFor.Items[requestFor.SelectedIndex],id=1,weekDay=choosedDate.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString()});
        listview_MenuItem.ItemsSource=selectedDates;

    }
```

I need one more help for deleting that item from List after clicking on Delete button.

```
public void onDeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //How delete particular item from list
        }
```

My Xaml Code -

```
<StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="20">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="I need to apply for a " TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.TextColor}"/>
            <Picker x:Name="requestFor" WidthRequest="150">             
            </Picker>
        </StackLayout> 

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Choose date:" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.TextColor}" />
            <DatePicker x:Name="choosedDate" WidthRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Date="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}">
                <DatePicker.Format> dd-MMM-yyyy</DatePicker.Format>
            </DatePicker>
            <Button Clicked="onAddClicked" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="70" Text="  Add  " BackgroundColor="#ed1f29"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <ListView x:Name ="listview_MenuItem"   BackgroundColor="#ffffcc" RowHeight="75"  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <ViewCell>
                  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                  <Grid HeightRequest="0.5" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="30">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                           <Label Text="{Binding dateSelected}" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.TextColor}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                           <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding requestFor}"
                                  TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.commonButtonBackgroundColor}"/><Label Text=" - "/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding weekDay}" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.TextColor}"
                                  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                           </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                            <Button WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="30" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.btnTextColor}" BackgroundColor="#ed1f29" Clicked="onDeleteClicked" Text="Delete"  FontSize="12" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
<!--                           <Image Source="delete.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="45"/>                             -->
                          </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

This is how my list-

```
List<dateListModel> selectedDates = new List<dateListModel>{ };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more code, selectedDates in which model does this exist? Do you use BindingContext?

Comment: Try to use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`.

Comment: **ObservableCollection** is completely new for me. No any option with **List**

Comment: Use it like `List`, but `ObservableCollection` will notify UI, that some items were added or removed.

Comment: Hi @EgorGromadskiy It worked for me. Thanks. I used-   **ObservableCollection<dateListModel> model = new ObservableCollection<dateListModel>();** instead of List<dateListModel> selectedDates = new List<dateListModel>{ };

Comment: Can you please tell me how to delete/remove items from this ObservableCollection. Because for every cell there will be delete button and I need to delete that date only from list of which delete button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<ListView x:Name ="listview_MenuItem"
        BackgroundColor="#ffffcc"
        RowHeight="75">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Grid HeightRequest="0.5" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="30">
          <Button Clicked="onDeleteClicked"
                  BindingContext="{Binding}"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>


public void onDeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var button = sender as Button;
     var itemForRemoving = button.BindingContext as dateListModel;
     selectedDates.Remove(itemForRemoving);
}
```